# Argument of type '(old: number) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I seem to always be fighting TypeScript.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
Argument of type '(old: number) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'
```

```
interface IPagination {
  pageNumber: number;
  setPageNumber: (num: number) => void;
  latestData: unknown;
}
```

**Pagination.tsx**

*Updated to show for the Pagination component*

```
const Pagination: React.FC<IPagination> = (props: IPagination) => {
  const { pageNumber, setPageNumber, latestData } = props;

  return (
    <>
      <button
        disabled={pageNumber === 1}
        onClick={() => setPageNumber((old: number) => Math.max(old - 1, 1))}
      >
        {strings.PREVIOUS}
      </button>
      <span>{pageNumber}</span>
      <button
        disabled={!latestData || !latestData.next}
        onClick={() =>
          setPageNumber((old) =>
            !latestData || !latestData.next ? old : old + 1
          )
        }
      >
        {strings.NEXT}
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Youre returning a number calling Math.max, try to open brackets and put it inside

Comment: Hmmm, no change.

Comment: Oh MB... the type declaration expect you pass a number to the function. Youre passing a function that returns a number. Can you provide a pagination component snippet?

Comment: Did you have the old number in your state? if so you can just do:
onClick={() => setPageNumber(Math.max(old - 1, 1))}

Comment: I have now added the Pagination component that I'm currently working on.

Comment: You're calling `setPageNumber` with a function parameter, but it takes `num: number`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `setPageNumber` is a state-setting function passed in from a `useState` hook in the parent, the correct type for it is not `(num: number) => void`, but rather `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>`, which expands to `(value: React.SetStateAction<number>) => void`.

`React.SetStateAction<number>`, in turn, expands to `number | ((prevState: number) => number)`. So the final type for `setPageNumber` is

```
(value: number | ((prevState: number) => number)) => void
```

Comment: Ok, based on this response, it would seem sending state-setting functions is bad practice.  Maybe I'm wrong.  setPageNumber is a useState hook.

Comment: I never said anything about it being a bad practice. It's a common and reasonable way of controlling parent state from a child. It's only a bad practice if you're passing the function through several layers of components - in that case you'd be better off using a [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext). Just make sure to annotate it with the correct type (`Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>`) in your prop types.